# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: [object ProgressEvent] with next JS/typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, swc-compiler

I'm new to nextJS and typescript. I'm trying to create simple blog with nextJS/typescript and sanity CMS backend. When I run dev, it successfully compiles but then I get the following Unhandled Runtime Error Error.

OS: MacOS monterey(M1)
Node: v18.12.1
NextJS: 12.3
typescript: 4.8

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: [object ProgressEvent]

Call Stack
Object.getProperError
node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js (25:0)
Object.eval
node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (574:39)
step
node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js (102:0)
Object.eval [as next]
node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js (83:45)
asyncGeneratorStep
node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js (23:0)
_next
node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js (12:0)
```

I've tried deleting/re-installing node_modules and package.json and that didn't work. Not sure if it's a dependency problem. Could it be that the _async_to_generator.js file is not handling an async function/promise? Do I need to change SWC back to babel complier. Any ideas? anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit late to the discussion, if you're using Sanity, the issue might be related to the CORS origins configuration for hosts allowed to connect to your project's API. For instance, you may need to add "http://localhost:3000" and other required hosts. You can manage these settings through the project's admin dashboard, under the API section.